# How to replace specific values in columns only if it is the only one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe:

```
id  val1                val2
1   "he bought 0"       "0"
2   "0"                 "0-the student"
```

i'd like to replace 0 with emptiness ("") but only in cases of "0". so for example "0-the student" shouldn't turn into "-the student". How could i do that? desired result is:

```
id  val1                val2
1   "he bought 0"       ""
2   ""                 "0-the student"
```

str.replace("0", "") will change "0-the student" and "he bought 0" too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply:

```
df[df == "0"] = ""
```

---

```
id        val1           val2
0  he bought 0               
1               0-the student
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have right now:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'val1': ["he bought 0", "0"], 'val2': ["0", "0-the student"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

Cycling through each column, then each row. If element == "0", replace with ""

```
for c, col in enumerate(d):
    for r, row in enumerate(d[col]):
        if row == "0":
            d[col][r] = ""
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```